# Get a row from one table and check the corresponding row in the other table if exists the add this row to the next of the first table row

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a table say A which has some rows and 'Id' column as a primary key. And other table B and it has the 'TabAId' and references the table A id column.
Want to get a report like shown in the attached image.
Explanation 
I 'sql server' database
  select One row from the Table A and check the Id in the Table B, If exists then add table B row as next row(If multiple rows are there then also add those number of rows as next rows) else go further.

Tried with case statement which appends to the row, not adds as next row.
With join also happens same only.

It may be easy through programming language like php or scripting like jquery and ajax but I want it through sql server only. It helps me for the further requirements.

So please someone help me.
[image]

Edited:

```
create table tabA(id int not null primary key,
name varchar(20) null,age int null)

insert into tabA values(1,'Sudeep',35),
(2,'Darshan',34)

create table tabB(A_id int not null,nickname varchar(20) null )

insert into tabB values(1,'Kiccha'),
(1,'Nalla'),
(2,'Boss')
```

output should be like below

```
    Id | name        | age  |
    ------------------------
    1  | Sudeep      | 35   |
    ------------------------
       | *Kichha     |      |
    ------------------------
       | *Nalla      |      |
    ------------------------
    2  | Darshan     | 34   |
    ------------------------
       | *Boss       |      |
    ------------------------
```

Comment: can you share sample data...it will be helpful to answer

Comment: @Smart003 Actually I have referred multiple tables for the images shown above. Can I create example tables and give?.

Comment: Yes @Mahantesh....

Comment: @Smart003 I have edited my question please review once...

Comment: @Smart003 Thankyou for your ans, Is it possible to apply pagination to the query within the CTE as requirement : If I want to get 10 rows per page and if any nickname is present in the tabB for last row then get all nickname rows.? So total rows per page increases dynamically.

Comment: query updated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on the requirement i have done the following.

```
    ;

WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (
            ORDER BY id
            ) dn
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY id ORDER BY age DESC
            ) rn
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM tabA a

        UNION ALL

        SELECT *
            ,NULL
        FROM tabB b where exists (select 1 from taba a where a.id=b.A_id)
        ) a
    )
SELECT iif(rn = 1, cast(id AS VARCHAR(50)), '') ID
    ,CONCAT (
        iif(rn = 1, '', '*')
        ,name
        ) NAME
    ,iif(rn = 1, cast(age AS VARCHAR(50)), '') AGE
FROM cte
```

please let me know if anything needs to be added

***Edit***: as requested display the results based on the offset

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#cte_results') is not null
drop table #cte_results
/*
in order to achieve the second goal we need to store in results in a table then use that table to display
results
*/
;

WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (
            ORDER BY id
            ) dn
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY id ORDER BY age DESC
            ) rn
        ,ROW_NUMBER() over( order by id asc,age desc) off_set
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM tabA a

        UNION ALL

        SELECT *
            ,NULL
        FROM tabB b where exists (select 1 from taba a where a.id=b.A_id)
        ) a
    )
SELECT iif(rn = 1, cast(id AS VARCHAR(50)), '') ID
    ,CONCAT (
        iif(rn = 1, '', '*')
        ,name
        ) NAME
    ,iif(rn = 1, cast(age AS VARCHAR(50)), '') AGE,off_set,rn,max(rn) over(partition by id) max_rn,id idrrr
    into #cte_results
FROM cte


/*
the following query is used to display the results in the screen dynamically
*/
declare @pre_offset  int=0, @post_offset int =2

set @post_offset=( select top 1  max(max_rn)-max(rn) 
from #cte_results
where off_Set 
between @pre_offset and @post_offset
group by idrrr
order by idrrr desc
)+@post_offset


select id,name,age from #cte_results
where off_Set 
between @pre_offset and @post_offset
```

Results were as follows
[image]